# how to install multpile control panels into the one server?

Tags: linux

i am using cpanel whm in my vps. i would like to test `webmin,Virtualmin,OpenPanel` etc.

can i install multpile control panels to my vps? i dont want to damage my server, that is why i am asking this question. i am hosting multpile websites in my vps, i do not want to damage any websites. i would like to install and test other control panels.

is there any other way to test these control panels?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest that this is a bad idea. Firstly each of the control panel is either going to want to install it's own webserver, DNS server etc, or control the existing one, along with the other controls panels. They are going to fight for control of these items, most likely cause conflicts and problems.

Secondly, testing this on a production server that is already hosting sites, that I assume are important to you or your customers, is a very bad idea. If you want to test control panels get your self some virtual machines, either on your own machine or from one of the many cloud providers and test them on their, not on a live server.

Comment: thanks mate, you have been very helpfull for me. A+ help. thanks for your answer and ideas...